# Fast algorithm for approximate lookup on multiple keys

Tags: algorithm, lookup

I have formulated a solution to a problem where I am storing parameters in a set of tables, and I want to be able to look up the parameters based on multiple criteria.

For example, if criteria 1 and criteria 2 can each be either A or B, then I'd have four potential parameters - one for each combination A&A, A&B, B&A and B&B. For these sort of criteria I could concatenate the fields or something similar and create a unique key to look up each value quickly.

Unfortunately not all of my criteria are like this. Some of the criteria are numerical and I only care about whether or not a result sits above or below a boundary. That also wouldn't be a problem on its own - I could maybe use a binary search or something relatively quick to find the nearest key above or below my value.

My problem is I need to include a number of each in the same table. In other words, I could have three criteria - two with A/B entries, and one with less-than-x/greater-than-x type entries, where x is in no way fixed. So in this example I would have a table with 8 entries. I can't just do a binary search for the boundary because the closest boundary won't necessarily be applicable due to the other criteria. For example, if the first two criteria are A&B, then the closest boundary might be 100, but if the if first two criteria are A&A, the closest boundary might be 50. If I want to look up A, A, 101, then I want it to recognise that 50 is the closest boundary that applies - not 100.

I have a procedure to do the lookup but it gets very slow as the tables get bigger - it basically goes through each criteria, checks if a match is still possible, and if so it looks at more criteria - if not, it moves on to check the next entry in the table. So in other words, my procedure requires cycling through the table entries one by one and checking for a match. I have tried to optimise that by ensuring the tables that are input to the procedure are as small as possible and by making sure it looks at the criteria that are least likely to match first (so that it checks each entry as quickly as possible) but it is still very slow.

The biggest tables are maybe 200 rows with about 10 criteria to check, but many are much smaller (maybe 10x5). The issue is that I need to call the procedure many times during my application, so algorithms with some initial overhead don't necessarily make things better. I do have some scope to change the format of the tables before runtime but I would like to keep away from that as much as possible (while recognising it may be the only way forward).

I've done quite a bit of research but I haven't had any luck. Does anyone know of any algorithms that have been designed to tackle this kind of problem? I was really hoping that there would be some clever hash function or something that means I won't have to cycle through the tables, but from my limited knowledge something like that would struggle here. I feel confident that I understand the problem well enough to gradually optimise the solution I have at the moment, but I want to be sure I've not missed a much better solution.

Apologies for the very long and abstract description of the problem - hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do. I'll amend my question if it's unclear.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about a database and some good old fashioned SQL? Seems you are reinventing that here.

Comment: I had tried passing the tables into a database and then using SQL to do the lookups, but the speed of working across two platforms seems to mitigate any gains from using the SQL algorithms. I'm still looking into whether I can get around that somehow.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: I tried creating a local MS Access file - I assumed a local file would be quickest. It was still quicker to use my worst-case algorithm on the data directly than connecting to the db and using a query. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

this is basically what a query optimizer does in SQL land. There are fast, free, in memory databases for exactly this purpose. Checkout sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html.

It sounds like you are doing what is called a 'full table scan' for each query, which is like the last resort for a query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood, you want to select entries by criteria like

```
A& not B & x1 >= lower_x1 & x1 < upper_x1 & x2 >= lower_x2 & x2 < lower_x2 & ...
```

The easiest way is to have them sorted by all possible xi, where i=1,2.. in separate sets, and have separated 'words' for various combination of A,B,..

The search will works as follows:

1. Select a proper world by Boolean criteria combination
2. For each *i*, find the population of `lower_xi..upper_xi` range in corresponding set (this operation is O(log(N))
3. Select *i* where the population is the lowest
4. While iterating instances through `lower_xi..upper_xi` range, filter the results by checking other upper/lower bound criteria (for all x*j* where *j!=i*)

Note that this s a general solution. Of course if you know some relation between your bound(s), you may use a list sorted by respective combination(s) of item values.